# What to do about downspout that empties into gangway?

Tags: drainage, downspout, ice

We have a downspout that empties onto our gangway sidewalk. In the winter this becomes an ice rink. One side of the walkway is flanked by our building, the other is a small garden on our neighbor's property. We're trying to figure out the best drainage solution. We've talked to contractors about re-locating the downspout, but the consensus is it needs to stay put. We can't run it to the backyard as it would cross a door going to the basement. We're on good terms with our neighbors and they would likely let us reconfigure this area as long as they don't start getting water.

What can we do?
Thanks

**EDIT**
Just added another photo for more context. The door to the basement is followed by steps up to our backdoor, and almost the entire back area is paved. The downspout is circled in red.

[image: Photo of gangway]
[image: Photo of read doors]

Comment: Adjust the downspout so that elbow is higher and run it to the front or back along the wall.  You want at least a 1/4 inch per foot slope to the end.

Comment: What crip659 said, but in different words: have the downspout cross *above* the basement door instead of across it at ground-level.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It could be tough to route to rear since after the basement door there's steps up to our backdoor. Going to the front is possible (I think), but the downspout would pass in front of windows and would have to get around an old chimney.

Comment: The main thing is you want to direct water away from the buildings.  More work but it might be possible to reverse the gutter slope on top, and move the downspout to the front.  Excess water beside foundations does lead to bigger problems than some ice.

Comment: Thanks crip659, unfortunately when they were installed we tried that and the gutter ends up hanging below the roofline when directed all the way to the front. I hear you about the water beside the foundation, just don't where it can go...

Comment: The other suggestion is to go underground, but that looks like a big PITA to do with the cement walk.

Comment: Maybe you could close off the downspout and drain in elsewhere.

Comment: crip659 I think underground may be what I need to do, but yes a big PITA...

QTX, thanks, I wish. I'm no pro, but we've had a couple contractors out here and they all agree it needs to stay where it is.

Comment: No way you can reprofile the *gutter* to drain to the front?  Looks like you've got another downspout there.